# Map comparator using child element values

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary

I have a map that's declared by the following:

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>> groupList;
```

I'd like to sort the main map using values within the child map (in this case, "sequence". For example, if the map looked like this originally (the keys are the same as the groupID):

```
(
    [1] => 
        (
            [groupID] => 1
            [sequence] => 0
            [command] => DefaultState
        )

    [2] => 
        (
            [groupID] => 2
            [sequence] => 2
            [command] => Restart
        )

    [3] =>
        (
            [groupID] => 3
            [sequence] => 1
            [command] => Beep
        )

)
```

I would want the result after using this comparator to look like this:

```
(
    [1] => 
        (
            [groupID] => 1
            [sequence] => 0
            [command] => DefaultState
        )

    [3] =>
        (
            [groupID] => 3
            [sequence] => 1
            [command] => Beep
        )

    [2] => 
        (
            [groupID] => 2
            [sequence] => 2
            [command] => Restart
        )

)
```

I had asked a similar question but not directed at using a comparator function when defining the map. The solution to my other question involved using the Boost library and tables. I'd like to keep this fairly simple and use my definition above.

Different options would be to use the sequence value as the key for the parent map, which can be done but I'd like to use that as the last option. Is the order of a map not changeable? I'm new to this type of thinking for C++ as I'm quite new, and it's hard coming from newer languages where something like this is a bit easier.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should drop your PHP view of things and model C++ data structures

Comment: @DieterLücking I know, you're right, however it's a lot harder than it sounds. I'm working on it. How would one model a map on paper?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Slava on not using a map for this purpose.

My suggestion is to use a simple vector and sort it according to different rules. Something like this:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, std::string, std::string>> GroupList ;

GroupList glist ;
std::sort(glist.begin(), glist.end(), mysort<0>) ;
```

where

```
template <int N>
bool mysort(const std::tuple<std::string, std::string, std::string> &lhs,
            const std::tuple<std::string, std::string, std::string> &rhs)
{
   return std::get<N>(lhs) < std::get<N>(rhs.get) ;
}
```

Then you can quickly get access to objects n the vector via std::lower_bound and, when needed, re-sort the vector according to e.g. `mysort<1>`

Answer (score 1):

Though technically it is possible to sort `std::map` based on value rather than the key, I would strongly not recommend that, as it would lead to buggy and very difficult to support code. Key for `std::map` is not mutable and it follows `std::map` design, if you use comparator on value and modify it, you will get unpredictable behaviour. You may use `std::set` instead:

```
typedef std::map<std::string,std::string> Group;
struct GroupComp {
     bool operator()( const Group &g1, const Group G2 ) const { ... }
};
typedef std::set<Group, GroupComp> GroupList;
```

`Group` inside `GroupList` will still be immutable, so to modify an element you will have to remove and reinsert modified copy. If that not what you want you probably can store `Group` in `std::vector` or `std::list` etc and build an external index - what is actually done in `boost::multi_index` under the hood.